# Set value that is in an array property in material table

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm creating a material table. The datasource's element has property that is an array. I want to show in each column in the table the value of a member in that property like the following code. However, nothing is shown. Where did I get it wrong?

**Note:** The ngFor in ng-container I use to create multiple column.

```html
 <ng-container *ngFor="let vendor of vendors" [matColumnDef]="vendor.Name">
        <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{vendor.Name}}</mat-header-cell>
        <mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
            <span *ngIf="element.Type == 2 else textValue">
                <span *ngFor="let cost of element.Cost">
                    {{cost}}
                </span>
            </span>
            <ng-template #textValue>
                <span *ngFor="let textValue of element.TextValue">
                    {{textValue}}
                </span>
            </ng-template>
        </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
```

Comment: can you please add the vendors json in the question?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `th` and `td` elements as follows:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let vendor of vendors" [matColumnDef]="vendor.Name">
    <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>{{vendor.Name}}</th>
    <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
        <span *ngIf="element.Type == 2 else textValue">
            <span *ngFor="let cost of element.Cost">
                {{cost}}
            </span>
        </span>
        <ng-template #textValue>
            <span *ngFor="let textValue of element.TextValue">
                {{textValue}}
            </span>
        </ng-template>
    </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: Okay, let me try that